POST https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/completions 429 (Too Many Requests)
I am trying to use open ai api for chatGPT integration website project, i am using free trial but i use the website locally so i am the only one who sends requests, but indeed I still got that error in the console:
POST https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/completions 429 (Too Many Requests)
here is how i request it in javascript:
const response = await axios.post('https://api.openai.com/v1/engines/gpt-3.5-turbo/completions',{
        prompt: message,
        max_tokens: 1000,
    },
    {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: `Bearer ${apiKey}`,
        },
      }

I tried to use small message to the chatbot and waited for some time and tried again in case there is pressure on open ai server

Maybe try to generate a new apikey or link payment method to use it.
Similar to OpenAI API giving error: 429 Too Many Requests

Unfortunately i can't upgrade to the paid account as i am using it only for personal project, but i examined the rate limits of the free trial and i didn't exceed them also i tried to create another api key and use it but nothing changed (it appears that the key is used on the website but i have the same error)

Please note that there are no more free tokens available for the API. Verify if you have any remaining tokens if not its probably why its not working. Checkout number 12 at this link: https://help.openai.com/en/articles/6950777-what-is-chatgpt-plus

I understand but i am on the free trial of subscription

This is the correct answer that @M19 has given you. They recently changed the way billing works, and the api requires a pre-paid value in the account.

You may have to set up your own account, but it doesn't have to include a subscription. You just need to start with a nominal balance - no more than $10. You'll be surprised how long that lasts!
